# Finding shortest string in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I am creating a function that returns the shortest string within the given array.
If there are ties, it should return the first element to appear in the given array. Expect the given array to have values other than strings. If the given array is empty, it should return an empty string. If the given array contains no strings, it should return an empty string.

Here's my code:

```js
function findShortestWordAmongMixedElements(arr) {
  if(arr.length === 0 && arr.indexof(arr)){
    return '';
  } else{
   return arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
      return a.length >= b.length ? a : b;
    })
  }      
}

var output = findShortestWordAmongMixedElements([4, 'two', 2, 'three']);
console.log(output); // --> 'two'
```

Instead of two it returns three. Also `arr.indexof(arr)` to check if the array has some strings.

Comment: Reduce signature is :  `reduce(function(current_result, current_item, current_index), initial_value) `

Comment: Please read the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: Loop through array, check the type of the value using `typeof`. Create a variable that will contain the shortest string. Assume the first string to find as the shortest string then compare to the succeeding string found. Only replace, if the value is shorter than the current shortest string.

Answer (score 1):

This should cover your requirements:

```js
let array = [4, 'two', 2, 'three'];
let shortest = array.filter(v => typeof v === 'string')
                    .reduce((a, v) => a && a.length <= v.length ? a : v, '');

console.log(shortest);
```

Comment: Can you explain this for me? I dont understand arrow functions.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Wow. I'd be really interested to know why this answer got downvoted. Is it because of the edge case of having an empty string in the array? Surely you didn't think of that, dear downvoter?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (the important part is the `reduce` of course) :

```
var arr = ["a", 1, "ab", "ac", 4, "ade", "ac" ] ;

var short = arr.filter( (e)=> typeof e == 'string' ).reduce( (res, elem, index)=>{
  if(res==undefined || res.length>elem.length)
    res = elem;
  return res;
}, undefined );

alert(short)
```

What it does is the following :
  It filters the array to only keep strings, then if res is undefined or res's length is greater than the element's length then we store the element in res.

Therefore, adapted to your problem :

```
function findShortestWordAmongMixedElements(arr) {
  if(arr.length === 0 && arr.indexof(arr)){
    return undefined; 
  } else {
    return arr.filter( (e)=> typeof e == 'string' ).reduce( (res, elem, index)=>{
      if(res==undefined || res.length>elem.length)
        res = elem;
      return res;
    }, undefined );
  }
}
```

NB: I decided to return undefined if there are no string in the array because it kinda makes sense (you can still do a workaround with the empty string if you really want a string as the result)

Comment: What about non-string elements?

Comment: Just add a type condition to the if statement

Comment: actually, i came up with the idea of returning undefined if there's no string in the array, lemme update the code

Answer (score -1):

```js
function findShortestWordAmongMixedElements(arr) {

  if (Array.isArray(arr)) {
    if (arr.length == 0) {
      return "";
    } else {

     var result = arr.reduce(function (a, b) {
        if (typeof b != 'string') {
          return a;
        } else if (typeof a != 'string') {
          return b;
        } else {
          return a.length <= b.length ? a : b;
        }
      }, arr[0]);
      return typeof result == 'string' ? result : "";
    }
  } else {
    return "";
  }
}

var output = findShortestWordAmongMixedElements([4, 'two', 2, 'three']);
console.log(output);
```